# Memory taken by a program variable

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

I was asked this in an interview recently: 
If I have a program, that is platform independent (say a program in java or python) and it has a variable a that stores a positive integer, then the memory taken by the variable is different in different OS?

I personally think it is dependent on how an OS implements memory management and the OS architecture but still needed to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a program where the size of an integer varies, it is not likely to be platform independent.

> the memory taken by the variable is different in different OS?

It might be different, depending upon the language implementation.